# Google Calendar REST API returns 503 when adding very large group (20k+ member) as invitee

Tags: rest, http, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

We're using Google Calendar as part of GSuite for organization.

The current organization administrator has created a new google group (groups.google.com) that contains the entire member of the organization (20k+ member) called somegroupname@groups.someorganizationnamehere.com (name changed for privacy).

When making new event through Google Calendar web ( https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/ ), it seems that adding that group to invitee makes the "saving" process very slow (can be one minute), and for the event to appear in member's calendar took longer (can be 2-10 minutes), this is still acceptable since we're talking about large number of user.
But now, we're tasked to make a managed calendar web application that may add/edit/delete events programmatically (so we used Google REST Calendar API v3 https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events ).

While developing said app, we encountered problem that the API endpoint is very slow (runs for 1min 0.54sec), and then returns "status 503" / "The service is currently unavailable" / "backendError". But 2-10 minutes later, the event appeared in Google Calendar (as if the HTTP REST API call was a success).

This is unacceptable since our app needs to read the API return to save eventId to our database. We need that eventId for editing/deleting said event programatically.

Please see attached picture for postman screenshot.

Is there any solution to make Google Calendar REST API for event resource to work with very large groups without error?

It's just my speculation, but is Google REST API's HTTP server set to automatically timeout at 1 minute and return 503? As I tried sending an exactly same HTTP request with empty "attendees": [], it returns 200 and have expected response body.

HTTP request that works:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
Authorization: Bearer ***************

{
    "description": "Test 17-10",
    "sequence": 0,
    "summary": "Test 17-10",
    "location": null,
    "end": 
    {
        "timeZone": "Asia/Jakarta",
        "dateTime": "2020-10-17T09:00:00+07:00"
    },
    "start": 
    {
        "timeZone": "Asia/Jakarta",
        "dateTime": "2020-10-17T09:00:00+07:00"
    },
    "reminders": { "useDefault": true },
    "attendees": []
}
```

response: expected response (return event resource representation as described in https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events )

HTTP request that DO NOT work:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
Authorization: Bearer ***************

{
    "description": "Test 17-10",
    "sequence": 0,
    "summary": "Test 17-10",
    "location": null,
    "end": 
    {
        "timeZone": "Asia/Jakarta",
        "dateTime": "2020-10-17T09:00:00+07:00"
    },
    "start": 
    {
        "timeZone": "Asia/Jakarta",
        "dateTime": "2020-10-17T09:00:00+07:00"
    },
    "reminders": { "useDefault": true },
    "attendees": [ {"email":"somegroupname@groups.someorganizationnamehere.com"} ]
}
```

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 503,
        "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "backendError"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit: I'm reporting this to google's issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177013453

Comment: Have you checked whether this long processing time also happens if you add the attendee via UI?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, as I have written: ```When making new event through Google Calendar web ( https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/ ), it seems that adding that group to invitee makes the "saving" process very slow (can be one minute)```

Comment: Hi, I saw you filed a bug in Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177013453. I'd suggest you to post an answer referencing this in order to give it more visibility.

Comment: @Iamblichus I'd edit the question to reference the issue. But there's yet any solution nor workaround so I won't post answer yet. I'll do it when it's officially fixed or anyone (including me) find workaround or fix.